Information extraction from borderless table
How can I extract value from the following reports with different report structures? enter image description here enter image description hereenter image description here enter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description here enter image description here
I have tried converting it to txt first, after that the entities from the report such as assets, current assets, etc. will be predicted using XLM-RoBERTa with NER

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
